# Two domains on one IP, added a subdomain and different domain's SSL gets protocol error

Tags: nginx, ssl, subdomain

I've been running two domains on one IP for years using SSL. One is example.com and the other is other.com. example.com has three names with its SSL cert; example.com, www.example.com and dev.example.com. other.com has other.com and www.other.com.

For the first time, I started up dev.example.com by just copying the nginx config for example.com like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com dev.example.com;
    root /var/empty;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name  dev.example.com;
    root /home/dev;
    index index.html;
    charset utf-8;

    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block" always;

    ssl on;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ...
...
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    root /home/example;
    index index.html;
    charset utf-8;

    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block" always;

    ssl on;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ...
...
}
```

Having done that, I can now access all three variations of example.com. However, none of other.com are accessible in that I get a (paraphrased):

> SSL_protocol_error

and

> This site is not serving securely

in Chrome while Firefox redirects to Google (my default home page).

The config for other.com is identical to example.com except for the dev subdomain. I did not set any location blocks for dev.example.com. The rest of the config file only contains ssl cert pointers and location blocks.

So I'm a bit confused as to why the dev subdomain took down other.com.

Comment: Double check server name spelling

Comment: Your configuration seems good with what you said. It would be easier for us to help you if you show the complete configuration of your `other.com` & `example.com` VHOSTs (hiding url & path of course), in order to determine the problem. Can you also try to execute `nginx -t` and see what it tells you please?

Comment: @Julqas `nginx -t` gives no errors. The config is identical for all the sites.

Comment: Make sure the SSL cert CN or SAN match your domain(s). If you want a single cert to support all the domains you listed, it'll need to be a wild card cert.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935369/ssl-how-do-common-names-cn-and-subject-alternative-names-san-work-together

Comment: @Paul The certs are not the issue. Each domain has their own cert and work just fine. However, now that you mention it, example.com is the only one using a letsencrypt cert while the others are Comodo. I wonder if that can be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution may lie in how nginx handles the default server along with how I created the config for the sites. Doing `curl -I http://example.com` showed some erroneous redirecting that may have made nginx look for a default server which isn't the one I wanted.

My solution was to actually spell it out better for the server. I did this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.example.com;
    root /var/empty;
    return 301 https://dev.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/empty;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name  dev.example.com;
    root /home/dev;
...

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    root /home/bc;
    ...
}
```